# Faithful modules in integral dependence

Tags: commutative-algebra

In Atiyah-Macdonalds, Proposition 5.1, for a ring $B$ and a subring $A$, we have

> There exists a faithful $A[x]$-module $M$ which is finitely generated as an $A$-module $\Rightarrow$ $x \in B$ is integral over $A$.

The proof uses the fact that $M$ is faithful. Namely, consider the endomorphism $\varphi$ of $M$ that is multiplication by $x$. Since $x M \subseteq M$, and $M$ is faithful, then $x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n = 0$ for suitable $a_i \in A$.

I'm unsure about why in the last statement we uses that $M$ is a faithful module. Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Here's a hint about why the last statement is useful. $M$ being a faithful $N$-module means that if $n \in N$ and $nm = 0$ for all $m \in M$, then $n=0$. Apply this to $N=A[x]$ and notice that we want to find some monic polynomial $f(X) \in A[X]$ with $x$ as a root, i.e. $f(x) =0$.

Comment: can I get an example to show that faithfulness is necessary? I want to understand by an example where there is a $A[x]$ module $M$ which is finitely generated $A$ yet $x$ is not integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use that $M$ is faithful, you'll only know that:

$$x^nm+a_1x^{n-1}m+\dots+a_nm=(x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0)m=0$$
for every $m\in M$. And you can't conclude that $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0$

An equivalent [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaithfulModule.html) of a faithful module is:

> An $R$-module $M$ is faithful if for some $m\in M$, $r\cdot m\neq 0$ for all non-zero $r\in R$

Comment: How do you prove the equivalence of the two definitions?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard use that $ax\neq bx\iff (a-b)x\neq 0$

Comment: Thanks! Let $K$ be a field, let $A$ be the ring of maps $f:\mathbb N\to K$, set $\mathfrak m_i:=\{f\in A\ |\ f(i)=0\}$. Is $\bigoplus_iA/\mathfrak m_i$ faithful?